# What is the name of the iOS dropdown widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to find the cupertino dropdown widget for like a week now and I just can't seem to find it.

Here is a picture of it:
[image]

Comment: I think you might be looking for `CupertinoContextMenu` class: 
 https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoContextMenu-class.html

Comment: @JaredAnderton yeah it is. I thought it was perhaps something like CupertinoDropdown. Thank you.

Comment: Trying to build my rep, and just found that comments arent super helpful to that. So I'm going to make this an answer. Hope that's alright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for CupertinoContextMenu class:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoContextMenu-class.html